# React form with useState for multiple values

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ez5djk?file=index.tsx)

It's a simple react form with typescript

Is it possible to use useState to capture the input fields data when the fields are completed

The form isn't just one piece of data but 3 - username, password and email

I could do it for one value with

```
onChange={e => setContact(e.target.value)}
```

but can I do it for 3 separate values

Comment: You can use a state object and update as `setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email: e.target.value }))` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).
First add a name property to each of your input, with values "username", "password", "email", then:

```
onChange={e => setContact(contact => ({...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))}
```

Edit: in React versions before 17, [events are pooled](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-form-multiple-values-rby6h9?file=index.tsx) and setContact update function is running asynchronously, so the event needs to be persisted this way:

```
onChange={e => {
  e.persist();
  setContact(contact => ({...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}));
}}
```

Comment: This errors when you enter anything in to the fields `Error: Cannot read property 'name' of null` - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-form-multiple-values-r8vmnj?file=index.tsx

Comment: Ah yes, the tricky event pool. If you are using a React version anterior to 17, you need to persist the event, because setContact is asynchronous, so by the time it reads the event content, the event has been re-used. ```onChange={e => {e.persist(); setContact(contact => ({...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}));}}```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-form-multiple-values-rby6h9?file=index.tsx

Answer (score 1):

Your handler could refer to the input name which you could then use to update the form object. There's a couple of issues with your syntax for this on the stackblitz - i.e the state object should be an object, not an array, so here's a full example:

```
const App = () => {
  interface IForm {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
  }

  const [form, setFormValue] = useState<IForm>({
    username: "",
    password: "",
    email: ""
  });

  const updateForm = (
    formKey: keyof IForm,
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    setFormValue({
      ...form,
      [formKey]: value
    });
  };

  const handelSubmit = () => {
    console.log("Form Submitted! Values: ", form);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="username"
            value={form.username}
            onChange={e => updateForm("username", e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="password"
            value={form.password}
            onChange={e => updateForm("password", e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="email"
            value={form.email}
            onChange={e => updateForm("email", e)}
          />
        </div>
        <input className="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a object in the state and update the state with cloned object.

Here you go, Code with results as you expect:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import './style.css'

const App = () => {
  interface IFrom {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
  }

  const [contact, setContact] = useState<IFrom[]>({
    username:"",
    email:"",
    password:"",
  });

  console.log(contact)

  const handelSubmit = () => 
  {

    axios.post(contact) //Example

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="username"
            value={contact.usename}
            onChange={e => setContact({...contact, username: e.target.value})}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="password"
            onChange={e => setContact({...contact, password: e.target.value})}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="email"
            onChange={e => setContact({...contact, email: e.target.value})}
          />
        </div>
        <input className='submit' type="submi" value='submit'/>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: This work but I get errors like Argument of type '{ username: string; email: string; passaword: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFrom[] | (() => IFrom[])' - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-form-multiple-values?file=index.tsx